# Try to use Base64Utils - but GWT compiler fails

Tags: gwt, base64

I try to use the com.google.gwt.user.server.Base64Utils to encode my image on the server side, but the compiler giving me this info (later causing an error):

```
*"[INFO] [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/.../....rpc-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar!/...////PictureFileDTO.java' 
[ERROR] Line 46: No source code is available for type com.google.gwt.user.server.Base64Utils; did you forget to inherit a required module?"*
```

Using GWT 2.1.0 and Maven in Eclipse.

What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: The error is produced in a DTO. Are you sure this DTO is in the server side (not in shared package) ?

Comment: Somehow, GWT is trying to compile this code. Make sure that this class isn't in a package that GWT will try to compile.

Comment: Thanks for the answers :-) It is correct that the DTO file and project is shared between client/GWT and server. That is why GWT compiler cares, I guess?? I will try to move the use of Base64Utils to a sever side-only class. But still I do not understand why GWT-servlet and gwt-user.jar have this Base64Utils if you can't use it...? Is there a good reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

The gwt-user.jar is the library you develop against, regardless whether you develop client-side or server-side code. It contains everything, UI widgets, utility-classes for the client-side, as well as utility-classes for the server-side.

The gwt-servlet.jar is used at runtime. I'm not talking about development mode, but about running your web application on some web server (Apache, IIS...). The gwt-servlet.jar contains the classes that are needed by the web server to run server-side GWT stuff.

So yes, the Base64Utils class is in both JAR files. Nevertheless it is not available for client-side development.

If you need something that work on both sides, check this out:

http://www.source-code.biz/base64coder/java/